# How to prevent bootstrap modal to close on form submit using codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have some issues about displaying alert message inside a bootstrap modal form if inputs doesn't meet the form validation rule. I'm stuck whether the form validates or not and I wanted to display the error inside my modal form, somewhere at the top.

Controller: Users.php

```
function create_user() {

 // set validation rules
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'Firstname', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Lastname', 'trim|required');

  // set validation errors
  $this->form_validation->set_message('required', '%s field is required');
  $this->form_validation->set_message('min_length[4]', '%s min_length');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
  echo "something";
} else {
  echo "something";
}


  $data = array(
    'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
    'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
    'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
    'email' => $this->input->post('email')
    );

  $output = $this->user_model->put_user($data);
  if (!$output === TRUE) {
    echo "data saved succesfully";
    // redirect('users', 'refresh');
  } else {
    redirect('users', 'refresh');
  }
}
```

View: userList.php

```
<div class="modal-body">
 <?php echo form_open("users/create_user", $attributes);?>
 <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
 <div id="error" class="alert alert-info"></div>
 <div class='error_msg'></div>             
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="first_name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">First Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
       <?php echo form_input(['id' => 'first_name', 'name' => 'first_name', 
       'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Firstname',
       'value' => set_value('first_name')]); ?>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="last_name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Last Name</label>
       <div class="col-sm-9">
        <?php echo form_input(['id' => 'last_name', 'name' => 'last_name', 
        'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required', 'placeholder' => 'Lastname', 'value' => $this->input->post('last_name')]); ?>
        </div>
       </div>

      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="phone" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Contact No.</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
         <?php echo form_input(['id' => 'phone', 'name' => 'phone', 
         'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required', 'placeholder' => 'Phone', 'value' => $this->input->post('phone')]); ?>
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
         <div class="col-sm-9">
          <?php echo form_input(['id' => 'email', 'name' => 'email', 'type' => 'email', 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required', 'placeholder' => 'Email', 'value' => $this->input->post('email')]); ?>
         </div>
        </div>

       <div class="form-group">
       <label for="password" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
         <?php echo form_input(['id' => 'password', 'name' => 'firs_tname', 'type' => 'password', 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required', 'placeholder' => 'Password', 'value' => $this->input->post('password')]); ?>
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default create-user">Create</button>
        </div>
       </div>   
     <?php echo form_close();?>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function() {

        $('#create_user').on('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('users/create_user') ?>",
                type: "POST",
                data: {"first_name" : <?php echo $this->input('first_name) ?>}, 
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json"
            }).done(function(msg) {
                $("#error").text(msg);
            });
        });
    };
```

I tried jquery prevent default but It seems not working for me or I have some mistakes writing the code. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: may be you need to use ajax to submit your form or use iframe inside your model body.

Comment: I did use ajax but got no luck or I am missing something.

Comment: Could you provide javascript code please?

Comment: @kasynych, I updated the question.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your ajax request on passing data. you can use serialize() method to send form data.  check your console for errors.

Comment: @RanjeetSingh, thanks I'll check now

Comment: min pleasure.. let me know if its working...

Comment: @RanjeetSingh `<?php echo $this->input('first_name) ?>` may be taken in ""

Comment: I tried but not working. @RanjeetSingh. Could you provide a sample?

Comment: missing apostrophe in following string 

'first_name) ?>

should be 'first_name'

Comment: @M.A.Naseer, not working.

Comment: Put a console.log statement in `$('#create_user').on('submit', function(event)` something like `console.log('on submit fired');` and check your console to see if that function is actually executing as expected.

Comment: @whipdancer, I also did that but no message appears on the browser console.

Comment: check your form attribute id. it must be <form id="create_user">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your submit function is not executing.  The default behavior of the form is executing and your jQuery code is ignored.

Change the button so that it is no longer a submit button and give it an `id`.

```
<button type="button" id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-default create-user">Create</button>
```

Then change your method so that it triggers when you click the button.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#btn-submit' function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('users/create_user') ?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"first_name" : <?php echo $this->input('first_name') ?>}, 
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json"
        }).done(function(msg) {
            $("#error").text(msg);
        });
    });
};
```

That should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for this. Actually my code works good now using only php but I'll rate this up coz it works too.

Answer (score 0):

if your form has an id then your code should work with the following changes

```
$(function() {

    $('#create_user').on('submit', function(event) 
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        alert("test");

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('users/create_user') ?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#create_user").serialize(), 
            success : function(msg)
            {
                $("#error").text(msg);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

there is an alert in your function - if you click on your submit button you must see this alert box - if not you know your function doesn't work

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out.

Comment: Sadly won't work. Something should handle the codeigniter form_validation_run like "if statement".

Comment: do you get the alert message ?

Comment: I believe your form is not submitted by AJAX call but a regular http form submit request after which your page is reloaded. inspect your form element in your browser if it has any methods which maybe overruling your ajax form submit

Comment: Unfortunately, got no luck.